# Add clickable button to ion-radio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do you add a clickable button to an [ion-radio](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#checkbox) component?

[image]

I want to give the user the capability to select an item and click on the question mark button for more information. But at the moment, it seems that I can't click any of the buttons I add. This is my code so far:

```
<div ng-if="identities.length > 0">
    <ion-checkbox class="item item-button-right" ng-model="filter.blue" ng-repeat="identity in identities">
        {{ identity. title }}
        <button class="button button-clear button-padding" ng-click="showAddImageTagPopup()" ng-controller="PopupController">
                <i class="icon ion-help-circled"></i>
        </button>                   
    </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do it using css, you have to set the `button` out of the `ion-checkbox` then wrap both the `button` and the `ion-check` in a div like this

```
<div ng-if="identities.length > 0">
<div ng-repeat="identity in identities">
<ion-checkbox class="item item-button-right" ng-model="filter.blue"
 >
    {{ identity. title }}

</ion-checkbox>
<button class="button button-clear button-padding" 
ng-click="showAddImageTagPopup()" ng-controller="PopupController">
            <i class="icon ion-help-circled"></i>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

and add these css rules for the button

```
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 4px;
z-index: 9999999;
```